# what happens when multiple kernels are sent to the device to be executed?

Tags: cuda, gpu

Suppose that I have send two consecutive kernel calls to the device. Does it wait to complete the first one or it executed them concurrently? If they are executed in parallel, do they intersect with each other for instance for memory access? What is the paradigm that is used for such case in CUDA?

Comment: If the kernels are launced on the same GPU stream, they are executed serially on the GPU. Else they run concurrently, independent of each other. If the same memory is being modified by these kernels, its the programmer's responsibility to synchronize the GPU streams properly. But if the kernels are only reading the same memory, no synchronization is required.

Comment: Worth pointing out that any form of kernel execution concurrency is only supported on compute 2.0 and higher devices, and even then only when the two kernels have resource requirements which would allow blocks from both to coexist on a single SM simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two consecutive kernel launches to the same CUDA device will run concurrently *if*:

1. They are launched from the same CUDA context.
2. They are executed on different CUDA streams.
3. The device supports concurrency (Compute 2.0 and later).
4. There are sufficient resources (registers, shared memory, thread blocks) to support thread blocks from both kernels simultaneously.

For more information, see [this section in the CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution).

As sgar91 commented, if these kernels share global memory, then it is the programmer's responsibility to write a correctly synchronized program to avoid race conditions. If the two kernels only *read* the same memory, then there can be no race condition.